# __RequestVerificationToken_Lw__ cookie being set

Tags: dotnetopenauth

In Firebug, I'm seeing a cookie with the name and value that I'm not sure should be set.

```
__RequestVerificationToken_Lw_ 
XNIEP5oKUIQJRTxePUDf Hol50J2N6Oc67JSVrE0nWGkJmPfBysMdUHfrKMZNlXv6FFLQexfh6MtB4TR5UlBlWDMja/ urLC1dm8S08SG DYJJYE87X0dQsYuTNnOTnzBTfTGYiMjFKHrBCrVhwK7R3FOJeG7XoQE6EE9l41Zt8=
```

Is it normal for this cookie to be set?
What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET MVC's [`Html.AntiForgeryToken()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470175(v=vs.118).aspx) method provides a built-in mechanism to prevent [Cross-Site Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) (CSRF). It automatically generates and sets this session cookie to validate that subsequent (destructive) requests come from this application, and were not posted in from an external site.